# What does 'a ## b' mean in C?

Tags: c

From usbtiny/defs.h (AVR libc USB code for ATTiny controllers):

```
#define CAT2(a,b)               CAT2EXP(a, b)
#define CAT2EXP(a,b)            a ## b
#define CAT3(a,b,c)             CAT3EXP(a, b, c)
#define CAT3EXP(a,b,c)          a ## b ## c
```

What is the ## operator? I've been doing this for 30 years, and I'm stumped. And google isn't helping because I don't think they're indexing those chars.

Comment: @karthikr: Not quite, the extra indirection is significant.

Comment: Type in `[c] "##"` in the search box here (_with_ the quotes), you'll find lots about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `##` symbol in a macro definition represents concatenation.

So

```
#define concat(a,b) a ## b
```

will mean that

```
concat (pri, ntf) ("hello world\n");
```

post-processes to

```
printf("hello world\n");
```

Documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation).

Similarly useful is the [stringify](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification) operator (`#`), with which this should not be confused.

A test:

```
/* test with
 *    gcc -E test.c
 * having removed the #include lines for easier to read output
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define concat(a,b) a ## b

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  concat (pri, ntf) ("Hello world\n");
  exit (0);
}
```

And why the extra level of indirection? As Deduplicator points out in the comments to his answer below, without that, it will concatenate the literal terms specified, rather than the macro substituted terms. A useful list of such pitfalls is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan).

Comment: In other words, it's a way of building tokens out of sub-tokens.

Answer (score 2):

`CAT2` and `CAT3` are the macros which should be called, the other two are part of their internal working.

```
#define CAT2(a,b)               CAT2EXP(a, b)
#define CAT2EXP(a,b)            a ## b
```

So, what happens if you call `CAT2`?

Well, first `CAT2` is replaced, which macro-expands the literal arguments:

```
CAT2(a_eval, b_eval)
```

Which is replaced by concatenating both arguments to make one token, by the `##` token concatenation operator.

Comment: @nsayer; Wasn't it? The extra indirection is important, even though you had not yet recognized it, and thus did not explicitly ask about it.

Comment: I'd upvote this is you said *why* the extra level of indirection is important. I agree it is, as I've run into this one before, but I can't remember for the life of me why.

Comment: @abligh: Otherwise the literal arguments will be concatenated, not after possible macro-replacements.

Comment: @abligh: Suppose you've said `#define N 3`, then `CAT2EXP(A,N)` would be `AN`, but `CAT2(A,N)` would be `A3`. (Or vice-versa, I'm not sure :)

Comment: @Deduplicator - yup, that's the one. Upvote duly delivered.